# Partition recognized, volume not

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, diskpart, drive-letter

On a Windows 7 machine, the internal hard drive is splitted into three partitions. Two of them work just fine, but the third one is not visible in the explorer.

In `diskpart`, `list partition` shows all partitions with their respective sizes. `list volume` only shows the two that are visible in the explorer as well. The third one isn't visible, so I can't assign a drive letter using `diskpart`.

On Linux, all three NTFS partitions can be mounted without errors, so I can confirm that the filesystem is working. How can I let Windows recognize the drive again? As a Linux user, I can't believe there is no way to fix this.

Comment: In the Linux operating system, assign a drive letter (if we define it D) to the volume that is not visible in Windows, and then back up the volume. Then we go back to windows, use chkdsk d: /f (D is the drive name) to check the disk in drive D and have Windows fix errors .If it does not work, try to use a three-way detection tool to detect if there is a problem with the hard disk.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "drive letters" in linux. But that's not how Linux works, Linux does not use "drive letters", that's an invention by Microsoft. In Linux I can just address the device using a device node, meaning there is no such situation where a device is physically detected but can't be accessed. Also I can exclude that there is a problem with the hard disk, since it works fine in Linux. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using a workaround. Recreating the partition table did not work, formatting the partition did not work either. But I created a small (30MB) partition, and a big partition in the free space afterwards, and then the small partition got hidden and the big partition was visible. So somehow it was not the partition itself, but the number of the partitition on the disk, which caused it to be hidden. I copied all the files back, and now the system is working again :)